# Google Static Maps API changes coverage area with scale 4

Tags: google-maps-static-api

As per the Google Static Map API docs, when calling the static map API with different scale information, the coverage area will not change and only the number of pixels returned will change (keeping everything else constant and changing only scale)

However, I have observed that keeping the centre lat, lon and zoom same, between scale 1 and scale 4 (I am using a premium API), the ground area is changing. I think this is a bug with the Static Map API.

If someone has an explanation for this please let me know.

For reference, I have downloaded the image at Scale 1, 2, and 4. Below are the links:

Scale 1 image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W1RG32PYG0eZ9lQecWUTWcCKZp7rBHQS/view?usp=sharing

Scale 2 image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19BOrCpSazABcYcqKTArzapQHT_UuE1dv/view?usp=sharing

Scale 4 image:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I__GzY-NGfIttFJBazwamvDZvdGOl1H5/view?usp=sharing

Between Scale 1, 2, and 4, the ground area should not change, but it is changing.

Comment: Premium plan users are entitled to direct support by Google engineers. Reach out to support team at Google via your support portal and they will check this issue for you.

Comment: You can file a bug in Google's Public Issue Tracker [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker) for the Google engineers to further investigate and to confirm if this is an intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As per testing, it seems that there is a `maximum` **zoom level** for each **scale** used. Take for example, at "scale=4" the maximum zoom level is 20:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.75437,-122.44712&zoom=20&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&scale=4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

If you adjust the zoom level higher to 21 with scale=4, the image doesn't change or zoom in anymore.

This is the same with the scale of 2 and maximum zoom level of 21 for this specific address.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.75437,-122.44712&zoom=21&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&scale=2&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```